passenger_wsgi.py not responding while deploying django project on cpanel
I am trying to deploy my django project on cpanel for the first time. The problem I am dealing with is that when I create a python app in cpanel, the passenger_wsgi.py file is created but does not run as expected.
These are the steps I have taken so far:

first I cloned my project
then I started to setup a python application from cpanel

a passenger_wsgi.py file and two folders named tmp and public are now created in my project directory(as you can see in the screenshot).
(https://i.sstatic.net/hEZeI.png)
As I saw in youtube videos, in this step I must be able to see a message in my web url saying:
it works!
python x.y.z

(https://i.sstatic.net/QmT63.png)
but it does not show this message and only error 403 is retrieving (you can see the response in the screenshot)
